# C++ use of public variables from different classes

Tags: c++, oop

I want to access public variables from different classes in C++. I am having trouble to do it. For exemple, I have

```
class A{
  public:
  int x;
  int getX();
};
```

After that, I want to use `x` in a `class B`. There is no inheritance between `class A` and `class B`, they are just two separate classes. The problem is that, in `class B` I do not have an object of type `A` and so I cannot call the function `getX`.
Can you tell me a way so as to use the variable `x`(defined in `A`) in class B?
Thank you

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Make an object and use it. Data members only exist in objects.

Comment: Maybe you need to make a singleton instance of class `A`?

Comment: i think you're probably getting confused between the difference of a class and an object, see this link http://www.diffen.com/difference/Class_vs_Object for reference

Comment: How can I make a singleton instance of class A? I am sure I should use the function getX() in class B, but is it possible using it without having an object of class A?

Comment: It _really_ depends on what makes sense in the context of your actual program. `static` functions / singletons apply to different kinds of design issues than instances of objects. But we have no idea what you're trying to design. Very roughly speaking: if you only ever need 1 of something, then static / singleton could be appropriate. Otherwise create an instance of the class where needed.

Comment: Well, **which A**'s x do you want to get? If I have `class Person {public: int age;};` then I can't just get `Person.age`, that makes no sense. It has to be `alice.age` or `bob.age`, if `alice` and `bob` are instances of `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define them as static.

```
class A {
   public:
     static int x;
}
```

in class B, you can access it..

```
A::x;
```

But there will be only single instance of x, which will be shared between all the objects of class A.

Answer (score 1):

```
class b
{
public:
    void member function(const a &instance)
    {
        cout<<a.x;
    }
};
```

Access data member of class a through member function of class b